# Accessing symbols within strings in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, symbols

Newbie to Ruby here and I'm trying to figure something out.  I've got a situation where I have something like the following:

```
sql = q%{select foo from bar where var1 = :ugh and var2 = :moreugh}
```

Now, I can print out variable "sql", but if I just use puts and #{sql} it shows the symbols as above, ":ugh".

I'd like to be able to print out string sql with the values of the symbols displayed rather than the names of the symbols.

Any pointers out there?  Many thanks!

Comment: what is the `q%{}` syntax?

Comment: The symbol does not have a value, it is an object, like string or number..

Answer (score 0):

your example-code is broken, i assume you want to do a single-quoted-string `%q{...}`

and that is exactly what you get: one string. so there are no symbols in there, it's just ONE string. similar to `'...'`

Answer (score 0):

I think, assuming you are using symbols instead of string, You can use following query:

```
sql = "select foo from bar where var1 = 'ugh' and var2 = 'moreugh'"
```

So using `puts` or `#{sql}` will give you correct output.

Comment in case this doesn't meet your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

You have two errors. You need to use `%Q` to enable interpolation, and variables are included in the string in the form `#{:ugh}`. So, you want:

```
sql = %Q{select foo from bar where var1 = #{ugh} and var2 = #{moreugh}}
puts sql
```

But please, please, please don't do this, even just for a small project. You are setting yourself up for a SQL injection attacj.

Comment: Actually `"#{:ugh}" == "ugh"`.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want this:

```
sql = "select foo from bar where var1 = '#{ugh}' and var2 = '#{moreugh}"'
```

where `ugh` and `moreugh` are variables. But, you should do it that way, your system would be open to SQL Injection. Use bind variables in your DB engine instead.